# What is the purpose of the instruction ROL.L d0, d0?

Tags: assembly, motorola, 68000

I was looking at some code written by other people and at one point I found the instruction:

`ROL.L d0, d0`

Now, I know this instruction allows me to shift bits left n places, example:

`ROL.L #$2, d0`

it makes me shift the bits of the longword contained in the data register d0 by two positions to the left, where any bits released on the left (msb) will reappear on the right (lsb).

Having ascertained this, I deduce that an instruction like the one mentioned in my question:

`ROL.L d0, d0`

it makes me shift by d0 positions to the left the bits of the longword contained in the data register d0.

In truth, this is not the case.

I have also tried on Intel microprocessors but it seems that such an instruction is not supported.
Incidentally, on 64-bit INTEL systems the maximum rotation is 255 positions, while on 8088 microprocessors it is only 1 position at a time.

Update.
I thought I'd include the procedure code where I found this instruction. This procedure generates pseudo-random numbers:

```
rand_func1
    move.l  #$12345678,d0
    addq.l  #5,d0
    rol.l   d0,d0
    move.l  d0,rand_func1+2  ; d0 = pseudo-random number
    rts
```

Comment: Re "In truth, this is not the case": Could you elaborate on how you came to this conclusion? What input value(s) for `d0` did you check and what output did you get and what did you expect?

Comment: For `ROL.L d0, d0` the CPU uses a rotation count of `d0 and 63`. So if the `d0` register contains a value that is a multiple of 64, you won't observe any change to the value.

Comment: Even on a 8088 you can write the very similar `ROL CL, CL` which would rotate the bits in the byte-sized register `CL` (1st operand is destination) by **any amount** in the counter register `CL` (2nd operand is source).

Comment: @SepRoland: So is it modulo 64? I added a detail to my question, which is the code where I found the instruction.

Comment: For `ROL.L` and `ROR.L` the result should actually just depend on `d0 and 31`, since rotating a 32 bit integer by `32+n` is the same as rotating by `n` (I guess there are some special cases how the `X` and `C` flag are set when shifting by 32 vs shifting by 0, but I'd have to check this).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By virtue of what @Sep Roland told me, I did some checks and this is what I got.

An instruction such as rol.l d0, d0, rotates the bits of register d0 to the
left by the modulo 64 of the value contained in d0.

For ROL.L d0, d0 the CPU uses a rotation count of d0 and 63.
So if the d0 register contains a value that is a multiple of 64, you won't
observe any change to the value.

A modulo is the remainder of dividing one number by another.
So, one modulo 64 of a number is the remainder of this number divided by 64.
For example, the modulo 64 of 65 is 1, because when you divide 65 by 64, the
remainder is 1.

Code example:

```
move.l  #64,d0              
rol.l   d0,d0                   ; No changes, this is because:
                                ; Mod-64 of 64 is 0 because:
                                ; 64 / 64 = 1 remainder 0, because:
                                ; 64 x 0 = 0, so 64 - 64 = 0 
                                ;
                                ; so the code is equivalent to:
                                ; rol.l #0,d0, that is, no rotation

move.l  #65,d0              
rol.l   d0,d0                   ; Mod-64 of 65 is 1 because:
                                ; 65 / 64 = 1 remainder 64, because:
                                ; 64 x 1 = 64, so 65 - 64 = 1 
                                ;
                                ; so the code is equivalent to:
                                ; rol.l #1,d0, that is:
                                ; d0 = 65 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01000001
                                ; once the code is executed:
                                ; rol.l #1,d0
                                ; d0 =      00000000 00000000 00000000 10000010 = 
                                ; = 82 hex
                                            
move.l  #120,d0             
rol.l   d0,d0                   ; Mod-64 of 120 is 56 because:
                                ; 120 / 64 = 1 remainder 56, because:
                                ; 64 x 1 = 64, so 120 - 64 = 56
                                ;
                                ; so the code is equivalent to:
                                ; rol.l #56,d0, that is:
                                ; d0 = 120 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 01111000
                                ; once the code is executed:
                                ; rol.l #56,d0 (if it could be done)
                                ; d0 =       01111000 00000000 00000000 00000000 = 
                                ; = 78000000 hex
```

Comment: Or more simply, you can think about mod 64 as just taking the low 6 bits of the number in binary, `65 & 63 = 0x41 & 0x3F = 1`.  That's how the CPU physically does it; that's part of why we have power-of-2 register widths.